# Retaining text based on phrases in a pandas dataframe & removing all other text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe that contains text like:

```
Sunny, with a high near 82. Light and variable wind becoming northwest 5 to 7 mph in the afternoon.
```

but sometimes contains text like:

```
A 50 percent chance of showers.  Partly sunny, with a high near 61.
```

I want to manipulate it so that the temperature value (i.e., the 82 or 61) is retained while all other information is removed. So it would become "82" or "61." I cannot do this on a fixed index since the length of the dataframe entry is variable, as is the number length since it is temperature.

I want to use phrases like "high near", "low near", etc to parse through the string to find the temperature value. Is there a pythonically pleasing way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['temperature'] = df['text'].str.extract('(?:high|low) near (\d+)')[0]
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
                                                text temperature
0  Sunny, with a high near 82. Light and variable...          82
1  A 50 percent chance of showers.  Partly sunny,...          61
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex with pandas like
near (\d+) which shall find digits following near

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am new to regex/ string manipulation so I will look this up and investigate further. I am sure I will need it again.